# I don't understand this quote

Tags: grammar

Talent, **lying in the understanding,** is often inherited; genius, being the action of reason or imagination, rarely or never.

I don't understand this part.
What does it mean?

Comment: Are you having trouble with the grammar or the vocabulary? any particular words that are causing trouble? Also, what is the context. 'understanding' and 'talent' don't seem to be related, expect possibly in the context. Anyway, what do you think it is supposed to mean? then we can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Coleridge (who this quote is from, from what I can find), seems to state that talent is a result of *understanding* something (well), whereas *genius* is comes from the ability to reason or from one's imagination.

He states that, since the ability to *understand things* (intelligence?) is inherited, *talent* is often inherited, as talent comes from that ability to understand things.

He considers reason and imagination to be traits that are rarely, if ever, inherited, and therefore, the manifestation of *genius*, that comes from reason or imagination, is also rarely, if ever, inherited.

In short: talented parents often have (likewise) talented children, but a genius will rarely have a genius for a child.

Comment: Not a *result* of understanding but a *matter* of understanding.

Comment: He says talent lies in understanding. Whether that means it's a result of understanding or a matter of understanding I'd say is open to debate - if I could be bothered enough to get into the actually quite subtle differences between my phrasing and yours.

Comment: OK. I'm a little thrown off by the author's usage of articles here.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, what Samuel Taylor Coleridge means is, talent being a natural ability or quality can be inherited, that is, it can be passed on from parents to their children, but genius which is an exceptional intellectual or creative ability (like that of Mozart) cannot be inherited and it is often the result of a person's capacity to reason and imagine.

In other words, one may not be born with any talents but one can still develop some genius by sheer reasoning and imagination.

That's just my understanding of the quote.

(I see that @oerkelens has given a better answer)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly less cryptic rephrasing:

```
Talent, because it lies in the understanding, is often inherited;
genius, because it is action of reason or imagination, rarely or never.
```

The author seems to have been reading [too much Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar#Ablative_absolute) prior to writing this sentence.